# Linphone import fail in Intellij Idea even after download from Maven Repo is completed

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, import, gradle-kotlin-dsl, linphone-sdk

## **Background:**

I am a building VoIP transfer proxy application in **Kotlin** which **will run in Server**.

This application registers and accepts SIP calls from SIP server as SIP client, and converts the SIP signals and media stream into private protocol and transfer to a MCU board which plays and collects audio.

The private protocol part is done now, and I am trying to use Linphone SDK for the SIP part runs in the application.

## Problem:

When I use Linphone SDK in Android Studio, everything works fine, and now I have the client side APK done, which is working perfectly.

But when I try to use **IntelliJ Idea** to import, I have import problem like this. The import package is not found by gradle.

[image]

As below, in "build.gradle.kts" file, I have added the repository & dependencies

[image]

And the sync returns OK with files confirmed exist in

"C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.linphone\linphone-sdk-android\5.2.15"

[image]

Although all these are done, but I still cannot have the import directive to be able to import the SDK module.

Any idea where I am missing out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it something to do with the Android Archive (.aar) rather than JAR file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our SDK is for Android only, you won't be able to use it as a standard library for another platform.

Let me also remind you that our SDK is licensed under GPLv3 license, so you must publish all your code under the same license or purchase a private license from Belledonne Communication (see linphone.org website).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assumed so, so I am making changes on the client side too so that all the calls are on my own private MAG Protocol without the SIP part now.

Comment: Any plan to release a standard lib version rather than android only?

Comment: Not in Kotlin, no. Our library is only available in C / C++ / C# for desktops.

Comment: putting the C/C++ package into a java package to import, would be great too as it can be used in a lot of Java/Kotliln projects.